# Compare two maps to find out if one map is > another map

Tags: apex, trigger

Say I have two maps

```
map1 -- > {Bob=115, Joe=75, Kyle=5, Max=20}

map2 --> {Bob=52, Joe=71, Kyle=4, Max=20}
```

and I'm trying to find if the integer values in Map1 are greater than the values in map2. If they're greater than it's all good....if any of them is not greater, then that's bad throw an error and stop the DML operation.

a better view of the actual code.

a chunk of a handler

```
public static Map<String, Integer> userTotals() {
    Map<String, Integer> mapUsed = new Map<String, Integer>();
    AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [
        SELECT Department__c, Count(Id)
        FROM User
        WHERE
            Profile.UserLicense.Name = 'Salesforce'
            AND isActive = true
            AND Department__c != null
            AND Department__c != 'None'
        GROUP BY Department__c
    ];

    for (AggregateResult ar : groupedResults) {
        string varDepartment = string.valueOf(ar.get('Department__c'));
        integer varTotal = integer.valueOf(string.valueOf(ar.get('Expr0')));
        mapUsed.put(varDepartment, varTotal);
    }
    return mapUsed;
}

public static Map<String, Integer> allocationAmount() {
    Map<String, Integer> mapAllocated = new Map<String, Integer>();
    Department__c[] depMap = [SELECT Id, Name, Allocated_Licenses__c FROM Department__c];

    for (Department__c dl : depMap) {
        string varDepartment = string.valueof(dl.get('Name'));
        integer varTotal = integer.valueOf(string.valueOf(dl.get('Allocated_Licenses__c')));
        mapAllocated.put(varDepartment, varTotal);
    }
    return mapAllocated;
}
```

Trigger

```
if (Trigger.isAfter) {
    Map<String, Integer> mapUsed = UserHandler.userTotals();
    Map<String, Integer> mapAllocated = UserHandler.allocationAmount();
    //spot i've been messing around with for loops and having brain farts
    for (string key : mapAllocated.values()) {
        if (
            mapAllocated.get(key) <= mapAllocated.get(key)
        ) //i know this is broken because i want the if check to run for each pair and not just one before returning
        {
            return;
        } else {
            //addError
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see some obvious errors. Like `mapAllocated.values()` gets you the list of values and not the keys. What is the point of this `if(mapAllocated.get(key) <= mapAllocated.get(key))`? May be a typo error while posting the question?

Comment: As per arut, above, you need to use `mapAllocated.keySet()` instead but you also need to consider that the two maps may not actually share the same set of keys so you might like to compare the key sets using `equals`, for example. There are other options for such comparisons.